# Problem with error "Missing delimiter (.inserted)" with arrays

Tags: missing

I'm having some problems with this error and I don't know what to do. I have to use a certain template and it doesn't work anymore. Before it used to.

```
\documentclass[sn-mathphys]{sn-jnl}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\left.
  \begin{array}{l}
  \left.
  \begin{array}{l}
  \displaystyle{\vec{u}_{h,N}^{m}, \vec{u}_{h,N}^{m-1} \in W_{h}^{s}}\\
  W_{h}^{s}\,\,\mbox{vectorial space}
  \end{array}\right|
  \Rightarrow \displaystyle{\frac{\vec{u}_{h,N}^{m} - \vec{u}_{h,N}^{m-1}}{\tau/N} \in W_{h}^{s}}\\
  \left.
  \begin{array}{l}
  \displaystyle{\vec{\omega}_{h,N}^{m} \in {\cal W}_{h}}\\
  \displaystyle{\vec{\omega}_{h,N}^{m} = \vec{\omega}_{h,N}^{m}\vert_{\Omega_{s}}}
  \end{array}\right|
  \Rightarrow \vec{\omega}_{h,N}^{m} \in W_{h}^{s}\\
  \end{array}\right|
  \Rightarrow \vec{\theta}_{h,N}^{m} \in W_{h}^{s}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: As I don't have you class installed, I replaced it with the report class and loaded `amsmath`. There was no problem with the compilation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For very mysterious reasons the class loads the `program` package that serves essentially no purpose.

This has the nasty effect that `|` cannot be used as a delimiter.

Use `\right\rvert` instead.

On the other hand, you can improve your output.

```
\documentclass[sn-mathphys]{sn-jnl}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
% outer block
\left.
\begin{aligned}
  % top block
& \left.
  \begin{aligned}
    &\vec{u}_{h,N}^{\,m}, \vec{u}_{h,N}^{\,m-1} \in W_{h}^{s}
    \\
    &W_{h}^{s}\text{ vector space}
  \end{aligned}
  \right\rvert
  \Rightarrow
  \frac{\vec{u}_{h,N}^{\,m} - \vec{u}_{h,N}^{\,m-1}}{\tau/N} \in W_{h}^{s}
\\
  % bottom block
& \left.
  \begin{aligned}
    &\vec{\omega}_{h,N}^{\,m} \in \mathcal{W}_{h}\\
    &\vec{\omega}_{h,N}^{\,m} = \vec{\omega}_{h,N}^{\,m}\vert_{\Omega_{s}}
  \end{aligned}
  \right\rvert
  \Rightarrow
  \vec{\omega}_{h,N}^{\,m} \in W_{h}^{s}
\end{aligned}
\right\rvert
\Rightarrow
\vec{\theta}_{h,N}^{\,m} \in W_{h}^{s}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Train yourself to use `\,` in the exponents to `\vec{}`

Also, the standard name in English is *vector space* (not vectorial); this is a common error for speakers of Italian or French.